# Loss of communication with openSUSE 13.2 server

Tags: linux, logging, server-crashes

Around three times a month (in varying intervals) I lose all communication with one of my (hardware-wise very old) servers. It simply stops answering to any network requests and even directly plugging in monitor and keyboard yields no reaction, the machine seems to be completly dead. However, the fans are still running and the LEDs show normal behaviour.

The machine is running openSUSE 13.2 and I can't seem to find any indication of issues in the log files. The last `journalctl` entries before the manual reboot I have to perform contain only periodic cron logging:

```
Aug 08 08:55:37 linux-swnh systemd-journal[160]: Runtime journal is using 8.0M (max allowed 702.9M, trying to leave 1.0G free of 6.8G available → current limit 702
-- Reboot --
Aug 07 23:15:02 othello systemd[4477]: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session closed for user root
Aug 07 23:15:02 othello CRON[4475]: pam_unix(crond:session): session closed for user root
Aug 07 23:15:01 othello systemd[4476]: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug 07 23:15:01 othello cron[4475]: pam_unix(crond:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
```

No other logs in `/var/log` were written prior to the latest loss. Is there any other location where I can find an indication of the error or some suggestion which tests to run? Since the hardware running this machine is quite old I would not rule out some issue there.